# Inject factory into controller function in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I am trying to code a factory and use it on a controller

```
.controller('View2Ctrl', ['$scope', 'Alert', function($scope, Alert) {
```

this works inside the controller but when I am trying to access it inside a function it's undefined.

```
$scope.test_function = function(Alert) {
    Alert.some_method  ->   undefined. 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.test_function = function() {  // remove Alert
    Alert.some_method  ->   undefined. 
};
```

if you inject the service into a controller you dont need to inject into a function inside that controller
check this one :)